# Pass credentials or token from mail app to webserver to use with EWS Managed API ExchangeService class

Tags: authentication, oauth, token, exchangewebservices, apps-for-office

I would like to use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService object on the webserver that hosts my mail app.

Can I authorize using some kind of token or something else passed from the client mail app to ExchangeService  object on the webserver without the need to ask a user interaction to enter credentials?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can for some scenarios, like calling GetItem on the item that your mail app was opened on, or to get attachments of the current item. If you are interested in building backend code that can do more powerful Exchange integration and use OAuth, check out our new REST OData APIs:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx